# "Unable to find XXX.gwt.xml on your classpath" error in GWT

Tags: eclipse, gwt

After importing a Maven GWT project into Eclipse the debugger doesn't work, complaining that it's

`Unable to find ProjectName.gwt.xml on your classpath`

How do you fix this error?

Comment: As an FYI, if you delete a GWT module in your project, but have pre-existing run or debug configurations, you must also remove the deleted module from the list in the run/debug configuration as well.

Comment: I found that Davek804's comment helped me: I simply deleted the debug configuration (Run=>Debug Configuration=>right click and deleted the <Project>.html file under google's Web Applications on the left side.  Then I went back to the Package Explorer, selected my project, right clicked and selected Debug As=>Web Application. This regenerated and corrected the corrupt Debug Configuration. I'm not using Maven; I'm using Eclipse Luna Release (4.4.0).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It turns out that when you debug some GWT project as Web Applications, Eclipse does not append the module name (i.e. the gwt.xml file) to the list of arguments. I tried adding it manually, but forgot to add the complete package name that houses the gwt.xml file. The module should have been referred to as com.company.project.Project.gwt.xml, not just Project.gwt.xml.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I found that Davek804's comment helped me: I simply deleted the debug configuration (Run=>Debug Configuration=>right click and deleted project will run

Answer (score 0):

Try going to *Run -> Run Configurations* in the menu and then select the *Classpath* tab and add the missing project.