# No source code is available for type com.google.gwt.ajaxloader.client.AjaxLoader;

Tags: java, ajax, gwt

I am migrating an project someone else built to newer packages and I have traced the root of my errors to this
 `No source code is available for type com.google.gwt.ajaxloader.client.AjaxLoader; did you forget to inherit a required module?`
I am new to GWT and not really sure how it works 100% under the hood so I am having trouble applying solutions to similar posts to solve this error.

Comment: Can't you just use a de-compiler and drag the jar into it to see how it works ?

Comment: jd-gui is a very good option.

Comment: @Paras can you explain a little more?

Comment: Since, you dont have source code with you. You can use de-compiler which will try to turn .classs files inside your JAR file into .java files. Then, you just have to explore the code.

Comment: "I am having trouble applying solutions to similar posts": what did you try? Have you read http://gwtproject.org ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- go to [Maven Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.gwt.google-apis/gwt-ajaxloader) and get [gwt-ajaxloader.jar](http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/google/gwt/google-apis/gwt-ajaxloader/1.1.0/gwt-ajaxloader-1.1.0.jar) - it contains both `.java` and `.class` files
- save the `jar` to `war/WEB-INF/lib` folder in your project
- right-click on the file in Project Explorer (I assume you use Eclipse), select `Build Path` -> `Add to Build Path`
- enjoy ;)

Comment: I did that and it did not work. What do I do now haha

Comment: @Andrei - Well, I just tried that. I've removed my old `jar` and added the new one exactly the way described. And it works...

Comment: My bad; I didn't checked the fact that the artifact also has the source code in it, so you're right, it should work (I can't remove the downvote without the answer being edited first, as it won't let me; perhaps you can edit and add a comment mentioning that the artifact you referred also contains source code?)

Comment: I followed the steps above and I still have the same error.  The jar file is included in the build path and located in the lib folder.

Comment: Try to add `<inherits name="com.google.gwt.ajaxloader.client.AjaxLoader"/>` to your `*.gwt.xml` file.

Comment: Does its position in the xml file matter or can I put it anywhere

Comment: I think it should be after `com.google.gwt.user.User` and `com.google.gwt.i18n.I18N`. You can place it as the last `inherits` entry.

Comment: I did that and now this is the error I get --
    [ERROR] Unable to find 'com/google/gwt/ajaxloader/client/AjaxLoader.gwt.xml' on your classpath; could be a typo, or maybe you forgot to include a classpath entry for source? -- 

The jar is included in my build path, is that different from my classpath?

Comment: Try this: [“Unable to find XXX.gwt.xml on your classpath” error in GWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10746947/unable-to-find-xxx-gwt-xml-on-your-classpath-error-in-gwt).

Comment: I think these are caused by different errors.  My error has the the com.company.project already.

Answer (score 0):

GWT needs source code as opposed to `.class` files to do its work.
So any references you might have from your client code towards any jars, etc, need to also include source code.

In your case, you either need the source of `com.google.gwt.ajaxloader.client.AjaxLoader`, or remove any references towards the mentioned class, from your GWT code.

Comment: When I find the source do I just include it in the build path?  The .jar file is already  included in my referenced libraries

Comment: I'd expect yes, although I'm not sure if this depends on your build tool or not.

Comment: I have a jar with all the relevant .class files so I need to add all the corresponding .java files?

Comment: That's one option. 
But in build tools such as Maven for example, there are different artifacts that contain sources (for example you have `artifact.jar`, and `artifact-sources.jar`) so you might not need to do that, but rather download the proper artifact.

Comment: In the other answer to this post, Adam gave you a link. I suspect his answer doesn't work for you because Eclipse and GWT Devmode have different build paths. So take the artifact provided by him, and if you launch devmode via eclipse, then edit your launch configuration's classpath to also include that artifact.